# How to return data value from minted ERC1155?

Tags: solidity

I've minted an ERC1155 with some data, but how do I return the data?

Here's my mint function:

```
function mint(string memory data) public returns(uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        bytes memory bytesData = bytes(data);

        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId, 1, bytesData);  

        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true); 
        return newItemId;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is not stored, only passed to these hooks:

```
    _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, address(0), to, ids, amounts, data);
    _afterTokenTransfer(operator, address(0), to, ids, amounts, data);
```

You can see this in the code on github for the [OpenZeppelin ERC1155 contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/7be85b746f6e8fb194d8ec0a8025d8221767bd19/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol#L266)

You are free to do with the data what you need, by implementing these hooks in your contract.

For instance:

- store the data in state
- check the data
- emit an event
- ...